# Why is my load balancer responding with bad gateway?

Tags: amazon-elb

I don't have any web server running on my EC2 machine, but I still get a **502 bad gateway** message from the load balancer in front of it.

Why do I get **bad gateway** error from the load balancer, but no **bad gateway** error, when there is no load balancer in front of the EC2 machine, but just a time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load balancer regularly does health checks on its target machines, i.e. it sends an HTTP or TCP request (as you have configured it). This way it knows what machines in its target pool are healthy and can take requests and which can't. It's supposed to *balance the load* between multiple machines after all.

When your EC2 machine does not have a running web server, its health check fails and it's seen as unavailable by the load balancer. Since apparently there's no other healthy machine in the pool, the load balancer cannot forward any requests to anything, and thus answers with a 502 Bad Gateway status.

The difference to just timing out when you try to access your EC2 machine directly is that in the case of a load balancer, there's still something that can accept and handle HTTP requests and return appropriate HTTP error codes. When you simply have no web server whatsoever, the connection cannot be accepted by anything and thus can only time out.

Comment: thanks, where did you learn that?

Comment: Err, dunno, partly in vocational school and partly through experience and understanding of networks and HTTP. You may or may not find this exact info in the AWS docs.